# Passing large number of fields from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm creating a data entry page using JS, jQuery and PHP for a MySQL database with about 250 fields in a client table. I didn't want to have to deal with passing so many fields individually
between JS and PHP so I wrote a function to iterate through all the data entry elements and build the entire SQL insert statement to pass to PHP. For each data entry element I
created a custom attribute "fieldname" containing the name of the corresponding database field, as in this example.

```
<input type='text' fieldname='first_name' ID='txtFirstName' maxlength=25>
```

Below is the JS function and PHP code. I've tested it and it works but the idea of passing an entire huge SQL statement like this seems peculiar.
If anyone has had a similar requirement for passing large numbers of fields I'd like to know about alternative solutions.

```
function InsertRecord() {
  // Iterate through every data entry element with the "fieldname" attribute to create the field list for the SQL statement
  sql_cmd='insert into clients('
  $('[fieldname]').each( function() {
    sql_cmd=sql_cmd + $(this).attr('fieldname') + ',';
  });
  sql_cmd=sql_cmd.slice(0, -1) + ') values(';    // slice gets rid of the last character (trailing comma)
  // Iterate again to get the values
  $('[fieldname]').each( function() {
    sql_cmd=sql_cmd + "'" + $(this).val().replace(/'/g, "''") + "',";  // replace single quotes in values with 2 single quotes
  });
  sql_cmd=sql_cmd.slice(0, -1) + ')';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'nwcs.php',
    data: { sql: sql_cmd },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) { alert(data) },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Error', '<B>' + errorThrown + '</B>'); } });
}
```

PHP code:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo 'Record added';
}
 else {
   header('HTTP/1.0 500');
   die('Unable to insert record due to database error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: I would very strongly recommend you abandon this plan. You're opening up your database to arbitrary queries from the internet API.

Comment: Perhaps if you POST a JSON structure of the fields it would much better.

Comment: Passing a large amount of data is not peculiar, and is indeed necessary if you want to... pass a large amount of data.  What ***is*** peculiar is allowing the user to define the actual SQL code you're going to execute.  That's a *very high* level of trust you have in your users, giving them direct database access like that.

Comment: Pass the values as ordinary parameters; ultimately it's roughly the same amount of content, and with ordinary values you can use a prepared statement on the server and protect your database from flagrant abuse.

Comment: `POST /nwcs.php` with body `DROP TABLE clients`.

Comment: I recommend you to pass your formdata as array to backend, and only at backend build your sql string, of course, treating and validating the information received and, preferably, using prepared statement. 
As the colleagues above said, the way you are building your query would allow any query to be executed on the server, and this is a bad idea in every way.

Comment: David - I'm not sure what you mean about giving the users direct access to the database. Can you explain that?

I'm really not familiar with the whole issue of how this type of operation can compromise database security. Would it be better if instead of building the entire SQL statement on the front end, I passed the fieldnames and values separately to PHP then added the "insert into clients" on the back end?

Comment: @user2360649 *anybody* can issue HTTP requests to your application. Moreover, anybody can post whatever data they want, as well. You expect to get `INSERT INTO clients` and just execute it immediately, but when you get `DROP TABLE clients` you're also going to execute it immediately *and lose all the data in that table*. Aside from being destructive, people can also just make themselves an admin account with `INSERT INTO users (name, is_admin) VALUES ('bobby', 1)` (or equivalent) and have free reign in the system. Or do anything and everything they want.

Comment: VLAZ - Thanks for your info but can you answer my previous question about passing the field names and values separately? Also, I'm not sure if it matters but this app is for a small agency with just 5 users and nobody else will even be aware of its existence. So how exactly would someone go about attacking it as you described? Sorry but as I said I'm really not familiar with the issue of SQL injection.

Comment: "*nobody else will even be aware of its existence*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity -> "*Security experts have rejected this view as far back as 1851, and advise that obscurity should never be the only security mechanism.*" The most basic threat vector you have is a disgruntled (ex-)employee. Somebody with a modicum of knowledge has a bad day and the entire application goes down. But anybody else can just stumble upon the page if it's on the Internet, as well. There are people probing for unsecured websites all the time. Most of them use automated tools for that, too.

Comment: Thanks but you didn't answer my question about passing the field names and values separately. I'd really like to know if this is an adequate solution.

Comment: You can pass the data however you like. Usually key-value pairs as JSON is all you really need. Once you get that on the server you can process it into a DB record. A PDO library can even do it for you or you can use prepared statements, or otherwise make sure you execute 1. Correct SQL. 2. The expected SQL. The point is that the frontend should have any direct access to anything in the backend. Only data should pass between the two and then each can decide how to correctly handle the data.

Comment: OK, that's really helpful. I'll pass the field names and values without any actual SQL code, and add the SQL on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

Never build your SQL Query in the client side of your application. This is a huge security concern. Anyone can run any arbitrary query directly to your database this way leaving breaches to someone run something like mentioned in the comment by @VLAZ.

The easiest way I can think of is naming your fields with a prefix like `table_1`, `table_2` ...
This way you can iterate through your $POST array looking for your `table_` prefix.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if (startsWith($key,"table_"))
    {
        // Append to your query string or something
    }
}
```

Also, be aware of SQL Injection attacks which would be possible without user input filtering. You can start learning about it at the OWASP website(https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Comment: To repeat the question in my last comment, would it be better if instead of building the entire SQL statement on the front end, I passed the fieldnames and values separately to PHP then added the "insert into clients" on the back end?

Comment: Yes. This way you can prevent someone running arbitrary SQL to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines shown below:

```js
// simplified Vanilla JavaScript version of jQuery.post:
function post(url,data,cbf){ // cbf: callback function
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST',url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function() {if (xhr.status === 200) {cbf&&cbf(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));}};
  xhr.send(Object.keys(data).map((k) => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k])).join('&'))
}

// scan all input fields:
document.querySelector('.go').onclick=ev=>{
  ev.preventDefault();
  let dat=[...ev.target.closest('form').children].reduce((a,c)=>{
    if (c.tagName=='INPUT' && c.value>'') a[c.name]=c.value;
    return a;
  }, {});
  console.log(dat); // show data for upload in console
  
  // -- uncomment the next line to activate the posting of data:
  // post('nwcs.php',dat,response=>console.log(response))
  // -- (the above will not work from stackoverflow.com)
}
```

```html
<form name="frm">
<input type='text' name='first_name' ID='txtFirstName' maxlength=25 placeholder='first name'><br>
<input type='text' name='last_name' ID='txtLastName' maxlength=25 placeholder='last name'><br>
<input type='text' name='email' ID='txtEmail' maxlength=25 placeholder='Email'><br>
<input type='text' name='phone' ID='txtPhone' maxlength=25 placeholder='Phone'><br>
<button class="go">save</button>
</form>
```

The actual `post()` can not happen in this snippet, but the Vanilla JavaScript function `post()` should do that job for you in your "real" environment.

Your backend script `nwcs.php` then needs to pick up the JSON string and create some *safe* insert statements from it. Hint: use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!